# Install Shield Limited Edition WIndows service

Tags: visual-studio, installshield-le

I was using the Visual Studio installer project for installing my product. Now it looks like the official approach is to use Install Shield Limited Edition project. Now I checked in the Limited Edition project type, and there does not appear to be a way to install windows service. Also the support for custom action also does not seem to be there. Am I missing something ?. Basically will I be able to do the following -

1. Create a windows service installer project in Install Shield Limited Edition.
2. Add custom actions - does not look like
3. Silent installer.

Comment: has your problem sorted ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i create an InstallShield LE project to install a windows service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994725/how-do-i-create-an-installshield-le-project-to-install-a-windows-service)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at:

[Augmenting InstallShield using Windows Installer XML - Windows Services](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2011/01/augmenting-installshield-using-windows_19.html)

For the links to related posts.  Basically LE is limited ( upgrade-ware ) but there are clean ways of extending it if you don't want to upgrade to Professional. ( $1500 )

LE always generates SETUP.EXE's ( MSI's compressed inside ) so silent installation is:

setup.exe /s /v"/qn"

Comment: I believe recent versions of ISLE now support native MSI service functionality without having to do this.

Answer (score 12):

Install Shield limited edition **can install windows services** out of the box. Take a look at SO:[How do i create an InstallShield LE project to install a windows service?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13162618/477312) to learn how.

Comment: There's a huge difference between native support and out of process support.